# Elixir: __using__/1 is undefined or private

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using Elixir + Phoenix 1.3 and have defined an `Accounts` context. I wanted to use the `accounts.ex` file as an index to require in other modules to prevent it from becoming too big but I'm having trouble importing the functions from the other modules I created.

The structure of my files is as follows:

```
lib
|- Project
  |- Accounts
    |- accounts.ex
    |- user_api.ex
```

This is how my `accounts.ex` file looks:

```
# accounts.ex

defmodule Project.Accounts do
  @moduledoc """
  The Accounts context.
  """
  import Ev2Web
  import Ecto.Query, warn: false
  alias Project.{Accounts}

  use Accounts.UserAPI


end
```

And this is the module that I'm trying to import:

```
# user_api.ex

defmodule Project.Accounts.UserAPI do

  alias Project.{Repo}
  alias Project.{Accounts.User}

  def list_users do
    Repo.all(User)
  end
end
```

I want to be able to import my `Project.Accounts.UserAPI` module so that I can reference `Project.Accounts.list_users()` in my controller but the modules aren't being imported. I get the error `function Project.Accounts.UserAPI.__using__/1 is undefined or private`.

My controller looks like this:

```
defmodule ProjectWeb.UserController do
  use ProjectWeb, :controller

  alias Project.Accounts

  def index(conn, _params) do
    users = Accounts.list_users()
    render(conn, "index.html", users: users)
  end
end
```

Does anyone know how to import all of the functions from one module into another so that they are available for use? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `import` instead of `use`?

Comment: @Dogbert I tried that but my functions were still unaccessible from my controllers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to include the `__using__` macro and put all the code that should be compiled into the using module in there. Like this:

```
defmodule Project.Accounts.UserAPI do

  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      alias Project.{Repo}
      alias Project.{Accounts.User}

      def list_users do
        Repo.all(User)
      end
    end
  end
end
```